# Unable to soft delete record when primaryKey column name is set to anything other than 'id'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model

I'm trying to solve this error since yesterday. My primary key column name is 'departmentId'

Whenever I try to soft delete the record by the code:

```
$department = departments::find($departmentId);
$department->delete();
```

It gives me a "conversion to string" error. I have added the line

```
protected $primaryKey = ['tenderDepartmentId'];
```

to my respective model too.

As soon as I changed the Primary key column name to "id", it is working properly.

Comment: Set `protected $primaryKey = 'departmentId'` in your model.

Comment: @TheAlpha - Have already done that. In fact, this line too generates an error when I try to view the records. The view generates properly when I comment out this line.

Comment: plz dd($department);

Comment: Alright, the error is solved. I was setting an array as the primary key before. Now when I removed the [ and ], it works perfectly. Thanks.